# General feedback on utility module

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for general feedback on how to make this useful to other people.  This is a subset of underscore.js with some additions, and what I feel are improvements.

The code passes jslint and minifies well with clousre.

Please let me know what questions I can answer to receive a better review.

```
/*******************************************************************************/
(function (self, undef) {

    "use strict";

    // holds (P)ublic properties

    var $P = {},

    // holds p(R)ivate properties

        $R = {},

        // native methods (alphabetical order)

        nativeFilter = Array.prototype.filter,
        nativeIsArray = Array.isArray,
        nativeSlice = Array.prototype.slice,
        nativeSome = Array.prototype.some,
        nativeToString = Object.prototype.toString;

/******************************************************************************/
// GLOBAL MANAGEMENT

    $P.noConflict = (function () {

        // g is the single global variable

        $R.g = '$';
        $R.previous = self[$R.g];
        $P.molist = {
            utility: true
        };
        return function () {
            var temp = self[$R.g];
            self[$R.g] = $R.previous;
            return temp;
        };
    }());

/******************************************************************************/
// TYPE CHECKS

    $P.isType = function (type, obj) {
        return $P.getType(obj) === type;
    };

    // returns type in captialized string form

    $P.getType = function (obj) {
        return nativeToString.call(obj).slice(8, -1);
    };

    $P.isFalse = function (obj) {
        return obj === false;
    };

    $P.isUndefined = function (obj) {
        return obj === undef;
    };

    $P.isNull = function (obj) {
        return obj === null;
    };

    // detects null, and undefined

    $P.isGone = function (obj) {
        return obj == null;
    };

    // detects null, undefined, NaN, ('' ""), 0, -0, false

    $P.isFalsy = function (obj) {
        return !obj;
    };

    $P.isTruthy = function (obj) {
        return !!obj;
    };

    // shortcut as their are only two primitive boolean values

    $P.isBoolean = function (obj) {
        return obj === true || obj === false ||
            nativeToString.call(obj) === '[object Boolean]';
    };

    // delegates to native

    $P.isArray = nativeIsArray || function (obj) {
        return nativeToString.call(obj) === '[object Array]';
    };

    // jslint prefers {}.constructor(obj) over Object(obj)
    // has keys

    $P.isObjectAbstract = function (obj) {
        return !!(obj && (obj === {}.constructor(obj)));
    };

    // has a numeric length property

    $P.isArrayAbstract = function (obj) {
        return !!(obj && obj.length === +obj.length);
    };

/******************************************************************************/
// LOOPING

    $P.someIndex = function (arr, func, con) {
        var ind, len;
        if (!arr || typeof func !== 'function') {

            // prevents type errors

            return false;
        }
        if (nativeSome && arr.some === nativeSome) {
            return arr.some(func, con);
        }
        for (ind = 0, len = arr.length; ind < len; ind += 1) {
            if (func.call(con, arr[ind], ind, arr)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    };

    $P.someKey = function (obj, func, con) {
        var key;
        if (!obj || typeof func !== 'function') {

            // prevents type errors

            return false;
        }
        for (key in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                if (func.call(con, obj[key], key, obj)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    };

    // loop through space separated "tokens" in a string

    $P.eachString = function (str, func, con) {
        var regexp = /^|\s+/;
        if (regexp.test(str)) {
            $P.someIndex(str.split(regexp), func, con);
        }
    };

    // does not extend through the prototype chain

    $P.extend = function (obj) {
        $P.someIndex(nativeSlice.call(arguments, 1), function (val) {
            $P.someKey(val, function (val_inner, key) {
                obj[key] = val_inner;
            });
        });
        return obj;
    };

    $P.filter = function (arr, func, con) {
        var results = [];
        if (!arr || typeof func !== 'function') {

            // prevents type errors

            return results;
        }
        if (nativeFilter && arr.filter === nativeFilter) {
            return arr.filter(func, con);
        }
        $P.someIndex(arr, function (val, ind, arr) {
            if (func.call(con, val, ind, arr)) {
                results.push(val);
            }
        });
        return results;
    };

    $P.extendSafe = function (obj1, obj2) {
        var key;
        for (key in obj2) {
            if (obj2.hasOwnProperty(key) && obj1.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                throw "naming collision: " + key;
            }
            obj1[key] = obj2[key];
        }
        return obj1;
    };

    $P.clone = function (obj) {
        return $P.extend({}, obj);
    };

/******************************************************************************/
// GENERAL

    $P.someIndex(['Arguments', 'Function', 'String', 'Number',
        'Date', 'RegExp', 'Object'], function (val) {
        $P['is' + val] = function (obj) {
            return $P.isType(val, obj);
        };
    });

/******************************************************************************/
// TESTING

    // equivalent to IIFE but "nicer" syntax

    $P.runTest = (function () {
        var tests = {};
        return function (name, arr, func) {
            tests[name] = func.apply(this, arr);
        };
    }());

/******************************************************************************/
// COMPLETE

    self[$R.g] = $P.extendSafe($P, {});

}(this));
```

Comment: Welcome!  We cannot look for errors for you here, but we can certainly do a general review.  If you do come across errors, feel free to post them on Stack Overflow.

Comment: A general review would by smurfy!

Comment: Alright.  You may need to edit out the "look for errors" part since that's off-topic.

Comment: Done. It has been removed.

Comment: @Jamal questions do not have to be free of errors. The asker just has to *believe* the code is free of errors. The request to find errors does imply that he's not 100% sure there's no errors, but he doesn't know of any specific ones, and thus it's on topic (in my opinion anyway, and what the FAQ implies).

Comment: @Corbin: Oh yeah, I forgot about that part.  Well, the explanation has already been removed.

Comment: *"This is a subset of underscore.js with some additions."* - wouldn't that be called a superset by now?

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer - A superset would have to contain *all* of underscore.js. All you can really say is that their intersections and differences are not empty. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- When declaring variables, I suggest going with the `var` for each approach. Helps you in avoiding missing commas. Also, it's easier to read and tell they are variables especially when there are comments in between the set.
- Name your variables verbosely. It can help when debugging and development. You wouldn't want to scroll up and back just to see what `$P` was. Name them like what they are. You can setup a non-verbose version like how jQuery references `jQuery` to `$`.
- Don't mind the variable name length during the creation of the code. In the end, you'd still be using a minifier to shrink everything to single character variable names.
- I suggest your `getType` be in lowercase to be consistent with the native `typeof`.
- `isFalse`, `isNull` and `isGone` wouldn't be much of use. A direct comparison would be quicker to do and wouldn't cause that overhead of calling a function.
- Do note that [boolean promitives (`true` and `false`) are entirely different from boolean objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean#Description).
- Make comments self explanatory. A sample of this scenario is where one asks "What does `isObjectAbstract` and `isArrayAbstract`? There are no abstracts in JS." - and the comments don't really explain much.
- You seem to do type checks on some functions but others not.
- Instead of returning false on failed type checks, I suggest you throw an error instead. Return the `result` when it succeeded, `false` if it didn't (but did use the function properly), and throw an error if something is not right. Remember console errors that go like `"foo is not a function"` or `"Accessing property bar of undefined"`, same idea.
- Before you do regexp on stuff, try doing it without using regexp. In `eachString`, I assume you are testing for a string. You can just do a `typeof str === 'string' && str.length` instead to check if it is a non-empty string.
- I don't see the purpose of `runTest`. It seems to just require a `name`, an `array` and a function that receives the `array`. Also, there's a potential memory "leak" here. Calling `runTest` stores the function's results in `tests`, however, `test` isn't accessible outside the closure. The objects and it's contents will stay there, continually accumulating, normally inaccessible indefinitely.

Well, that's it. That's my rundown of the things in your code.

Comment: - all the functions are type checked.  If not in the initial calling function, than in the function it is used in.

Comment: - typeof is actually different from the other two methods I'm familiar with, as `toString` will return an uppercase version, and so will the `constructor.name` property.

Comment: - underscore.js uses one line functions as well.