# General feedback on DOM module

Tags: javascript

This module is dependent upon a utility module I previously posted:

[General feedback on utility module](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/30189/general-feedback-on-utility-module)

I'm looking for general feedback on how to make this useful to other people. This is a subset of jQuery with some additions, and what I feel are improvements.

The code passes jslint and minifies well with closure.

```
/*******************************************************************************
**DOM
*******************************************************************************/


(function (win, doc) {

    "use strict";

        // p(R)ivate propeties go here

    var $R = {},

        // (P)ublic properties go here

        $P = function (selector) {
            return new $R.Constructor(selector);
        },

        // (D)ependencies go here

        $D;

/******************************************************************************/
// GLOBAL MANAGEMENT

    $D = (function manageGlobal() {
        $R.g = '$';
        if (win[$R.g] && win[$R.g].molist && win[$R.g].molist.utility) {
            win[$R.g].molist.dom = true;
        } else {
            throw "dom requires utility module";
        }
        return win[$R.g];
    }());

/******************************************************************************/
// DOM RETREIVAL

    $P.el = function (selector_native) {
        if (selector_native) {
            var type = selector_native.match(/^(@|#|\.)([\x20-\x7E]+)$/);
            if (!type || !type[1] || !type[2]) {
                return {error: "mal-formed selector"};
            }
            var type1 = type[1];
            var type2 = type[2];
            if (type1 === '#') {
                return doc.getElementById(type2);
            }
            if (type1 === '.' && doc.getElementsByClassName) {
                return doc.getElementsByClassName(type2);
            }
            if (type1 === '@') {
                return doc.getElementsByName(type2);
            }
        }
    };

/******************************************************************************/
// DOM REPORTING

    $P.aZindex = function () {
        var z_arr = {},
            all_el = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*"),
            i,
            len,
            cur,
            style,
            z_index;
        for (i = 0, len = all_el.length; i < len; i++) {
            cur = all_el[i];
            style = win.getComputedStyle(cur);
            z_index = style.getPropertyValue("z-index");
            if (z_index !== "auto") {
                z_arr[i] = [cur.id, cur.tagName, cur.className, z_index];
            }
        }
        return z_arr;
    };

    $P.aDOM = function (node, func) {
        var arr = [],
            level = 1;
        walk(node, func);
        function walk(node, func) {
            if (typeof func === 'function') {
                func(node);
            }
            node = node.firstChild;
            while (node) {
                if (node.id) {
                    arr.push(node.id);                
                    // console.log(node.id);
                }
                level++;
                walk(node, func);
                node = node.nextSibling;
            }
            level--;
            if (level === 0) {
               arr.sort();
            }
        }
    };


/******************************************************************************/
// DOM MANIPULATION

    $P.removeElement = function (el) {
        if (el && el.parentNode) {
            return el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
        }
        return null;
    };

/*
*/

    $P.insertAfter = function (el, ref) {
        if (el) {
            return ref.parentNode.insertBefore(el, ref.nextSibling);
        }
        return null;
    };

    $P.isElement = function (obj) {
        return !!(obj && obj.nodeType === 1);
    };

/*
*/

    // update to conform to util style

    $P.eachChild = function (ref_el, func, con) {
        if (ref_el) {
            var iter_el = ref_el.firstChild,
                result;
            do {
                result = func.call(con, iter_el, ref_el);
                if (result !== undefined) {
                    return result;
                }
                iter_el = iter_el.nextSibling;
            } while (iter_el !== null);
        }
        return null;
    };

    $P.HTMLToElement = function (html) {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML = html;
        return div.firstChild;
    };

    $P.getData = function (id) {
        var data,
            obj = {},
            el = document.getElementById(id);
        if (el.dataset) {
            $D.someKey(el.dataset, function (val, key) {
                obj[key] = val;
            });
        } else {
            data = $D.filter(el.attributes, function (at) {
                return (/^data-/).test(at.name);
            });
            $D.someIndex(data, function (val, i) {
                obj[data[i].name.slice(5)] = val.value;
            });
        }
        return obj;
    };

/******************************************************************************/
// MANIPULATE CLASSNAME ATTRIBUTE

    $R.hasClass = function (el, name) {
        return new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + name, 'g').test(el.className);
    };

    $R.toggleNS = function (el, ns, prop) {
        $P.eachString(el.className, function (val) {
            if (val.match(/toggle_/)) {
                var names = val.split(/_/);
                if (names[1] === ns && names[2] !== prop) {
                    $P.removeClass(el, val);
                }
            }
        });
    };

    $P.addClass = function (el, name) {
        if (!$R.hasClass(el, name)) {
            el.className += (el.className ? ' ' : '') + name;
        }
        var temp = name.match(/toggle_(\w+)_(\w+)/);
        if (temp) {
            $R.toggleNS(el, temp[1], temp[2]);
            return;
        }
    };

    $P.removeClass = function (el, name) {
        el.className = name ? el.className.replace(new RegExp('(\\s|^)' +
                name, 'g'), '') : '';
    };

/******************************************************************************/
// CONSTRUCTOR

    $R.Constructor = function (selector) {
        var type,
            type1,
            type2,
            temp,
            obj_type;

        // $D object detected

        if (selector instanceof $R.Constructor) {
            return selector;
        }

        // window object detected

        if (selector === win) {
            this[0] = selector;
            return this;
        }

        // document object detected

        if (selector === doc) {
            this[0] = selector;
            return this;
        }

        // element object detected

        if ($P.isElement(selector)) {
            this[0] = selector;
            return this;
        }

        // only strings should be left

        if (selector) {
            obj_type = $D.getType(selector);
        }

        if (obj_type !== 'String') {
            return this;
        }

        // selector is a symbol follwed by asci

        type = selector.match(/^(@|#|\.)([\x20-\x7E]+)$/);
        if (!type) {
            return this;
        }
        type1 = type[1];
        type2 = type[2];

        // id

        if (type1 === '#') {
            temp = doc.getElementById(type2);
            if (!temp) {
                return this;
            }
            this[0] = temp;
            return this;
        }

        // class

        if (type1 === '.' && doc.getElementsByClassName) {
            temp = doc.getElementsByClassName(type2);
            if (!temp) {
                return this;
            }
            $D.someIndex(temp, function (val, index) {
                this[index] = val;
            }, this);
            return this;
        }

        // name

        if (type1 === '@') {
            temp = doc.getElementsByName(type2);
            if (!temp) {
                return this;
            }
            $D.someIndex(temp, function (val, index) {
                this[index] = val;
            }, this);
            return this;
        }
    };

    $R.proto = $R.Constructor.prototype;

/******************************************************************************/
// EFFECTS

    $R.proto.fade = function (direction, max_time, callback) {
        var privates = {},
            self = this;

        // initialize

        privates.elapsed = 0;
        privates.GRANULARITY = 10;
        if (privates.timer_id) {
            win.clearInterval(privates.timer_id);
        }

        (function next() {
            privates.elapsed += privates.GRANULARITY;
            if (!privates.timer_id) {
                privates.timer_id = win.setInterval(next, privates.GRANULARITY);
            }
            if (direction === 'up') {
                $D.someKey(self, function (val) {
                    val.style.opacity = privates.elapsed / max_time;
                });

            } else if (direction === 'down') {
                $D.someKey(self, function (val) {
                    val.style.opacity = (max_time - privates.elapsed) / max_time;
                });
            }
            if (privates.elapsed >= max_time) {
                if (callback) {
                    callback();
                }
                win.clearInterval(privates.timer_id);
            }
        }());
    };

    $P.peakOut = function (elem, offset, delay, callback) {
        var privates = {};

        // constants initialization

        privates.RADIX = 10;
        privates.GRAN_TIME = 15;
        privates.GRAN_DIST = 1;
        privates.UNITS = 'px';

        // privates initialization

        privates.el = elem;
        privates.start = parseInt($P.getComputedStyle(privates.el).getPropertyValue("top"),
                privates.RADIX);

        privates.status = 'down';
        privates.end = privates.start + offset;
        privates.current = privates.start;
        privates.id = null;

        (function next() {
            if ((privates.status === 'down') && (privates.current < privates.end)) {
                privates.current += privates.GRAN_DIST;
                privates.el.style.top = privates.current + privates.UNITS;
                if (!privates.id) {
                    privates.id = $P.setInterval(next, privates.GRAN_TIME);
                }
            } else if ((privates.status === 'down') && (privates.current === privates.end)) {
                privates.status = 'up';
                $R.resetInterval(privates);
                $P.setTimeout(next, delay);
            } else if ((privates.status === 'up') && (privates.current > privates.start)) {
                privates.current -= privates.GRAN_DIST;
                privates.el.style.top = privates.current + privates.UNITS;
                if (!privates.id) {
                    privates.id = $P.setInterval(next, privates.GRAN_TIME);
                }
            } else if ((privates.status === 'up') && (privates.current === privates.start)) {
                $R.resetInterval(privates);
                callback();
            }
        }());
    };

    $R.resetInterval = function (privates) {
        $P.clearInterval(privates.id);
        privates.id = 0;
    };

    $R.expandFont = function (direction, max_time) {
        var self = this,
            el_prim = self[0],
            privates = {};

        if (el_prim.timer_id) {
            return;
        }

        el_prim.style.fontSize = $P.getComputedStyle(el_prim,
                null).getPropertyValue("font-size");

        privates.final_size = parseInt(el_prim.style.fontSize, privates.RADIX);
        privates.GRANULARITY = 10;
        privates.time_elapsed = 0;
        (function next() {
            $D.someKey(self, function (val) {
                if (direction === 'up') {
                    val.style.fontSize = ((privates.time_elapsed / max_time) *
                            privates.final_size) + 'px';

                } else if (direction === 'down') {
                    val.style.fontSize = ((max_time - privates.time_elapsed) /
                            max_time) + 'px';
                }
            });
            privates.time_elapsed += privates.GRANULARITY;

            // completed, do not call next

            if (el_prim.timer_id_done) {
                $P.clearTimeout(el_prim.timer_id);
                el_prim.timer_id = undefined;
                el_prim.timer_id_done = undefined;

            // intermediate call to next

            } else if (privates.time_elapsed < max_time) {
                el_prim.timer_id = $P.setTimeout(next, privates.GRANULARITY);

            // normalizing call to guarante (elapsed === max)

            } else if (privates.time_elapsed >= max_time) {
                el_prim.timer_id = $P.setTimeout(next, privates.GRANULARITY);
                el_prim.timer_id_done = true;
                privates.time_elapsed = max_time;
            }
        }());
    };

    $R.proto.expandFont = function (direction, max_time, big_size) {
        return $R.expandFont.call(this, direction, max_time, big_size);
    };

    $P.expandFont = (function () {
        return function (element, direction, max_time, big_size) {
            var temp = [];
            temp[0] = element;
            $R.expandFont.call(temp, direction, max_time, big_size);
        };
    }());

/******************************************************************************/
// EVENTS

    $R.functionNull = function () {
        return undefined;
    };

    // createEvent

    $R.createEvent = function () {
        if (doc.createEvent) {
            return function (type) {
                var event = doc.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
                event.initEvent(type, true, false);
                $D.someKey(this, function (val) {
                    val.dispatchEvent(event);
                });
            };
        }
        if (doc.createEventObject) {
            return function (type) {
                var event = doc.createEventObject();
                event.eventType = type;
                $D.someKey(this, function (val) {
                    val.fireEvent('on' + type, event);
                });
            };
        }
        return $R.functionNull;
    };

    $R.proto.createEvent = function (type) {
        return $R.createEvent.call(this, type);
    };

    $P.createEvent = (function () {
        return function (element, type) {
            var temp = [];
            temp[0] = element;
            $R.createEvent.call(temp, type);
        };
    }());

    // addEvent

    $R.addEvent = (function () {
        if (win.addEventListener) {
            return function (type, callback) {
                $D.someKey(this, function (val) {
                    val.addEventListener(type, callback);
                });
            };
        }
        if (win.attachEvent) {
            return function (type, callback) {
                $D.someKey(this, function (val) {
                    val.attachEvent('on' + type, callback);
                });
            };
        }
        return $R.functionNull;
    }());

    $R.proto.addEvent = function (type, callback) {
        return $R.addEvent.call(this, type, callback);
    };

    $P.addEvent = (function () {
        return function (element, type, callback) {
            var temp = [];
            temp[0] = element;
            $R.addEvent.call(temp, type, callback);
        };
    }());

    // removeEvent

    $R.proto.removeEvent = (function () {
        if (win.removeEventListener) {
            return function (type, callback) {
                $D.someKey(this, function (val) {
                    val.removeEventListener(type, callback);
                });
            };
        }
        if (win.detachEvent) {
            return function (type, callback) {
                $D.someKey(this, function (val) {
                    val.detachEvent('on' + type, callback);
                });
            };
        }
        return $R.functionNull;
    }());

    $R.proto.removeEvent = function (type, callback) {
        return $R.removeEvent.call(this, type, callback);
    };

    $P.removeEvent = (function () {
        return function (element, type, callback) {
            var temp = [];
            temp[0] = element;
            $R.removeEvent.call(temp, type, callback);
        };
    }());

/******************************************************************************/
// AJAX
// onreadystatechange,this.readyState === 4 removed

    $P.ajax = function (config_ajax) {
        var xhr;

        // get

        if (config_ajax.type === 'get') {
            xhr = new win.XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('GET', config_ajax.url, true);
            xhr.onload = function () {
                if (this.status === 200) {
                    config_ajax.callback(xhr.responseText);
                }
            };
            xhr.send(null);
        }

        // post

        if (config_ajax.type === 'post') {
            xhr = new win.XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("POST", config_ajax.url, true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type",
                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xhr.onload = function () {
                if (this.status === 200) {
                    config_ajax.callback(xhr.responseText);
                }
            };
            xhr.send(config_ajax.data);
        }

        // post for form_data

        if (config_ajax.type === 'multi') {
            xhr = new win.XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("POST", config_ajax.url, true);
            xhr.onload = function () {
                if (this.status === 200) {
                    config_ajax.callback(xhr.responseText);
                }
            };
            xhr.send(config_ajax.data);
        }

    };

    $R.Queue = (function () {
        var queue = [],
            publik = {};
        function getIndexFromToken(callback) {
            var hold;
            $D.someIndex(queue, function (val, index) {
                if (val.callback === callback) {
                    hold = index;
                    return index;
                }
            });
            return hold;
        }
        function getBlockedProperty(item) {
            var blocked;
            if (item) {
                blocked = item.blocked;
            } else {
                blocked = false;
            }
            return blocked;
        }
        publik.addItem = function (callback) {
            var temp = {};
            temp.blocked = false;
            temp.callback = callback;
            temp.response_text = null;
            queue.push(temp);
        };
        publik.itemCompleted = function (response_text, callback) {
            var index,
                item,
                blocked;
            index = getIndexFromToken(callback);
            if (index !== 0) {
                queue[index].blocked = true;
                queue[index].response_text = response_text;
            } else {
                item = queue.shift();
                item.callback(response_text);
                blocked = getBlockedProperty(queue[0]);
                while (blocked) {
                    item = queue.shift();
                    item.callback(item.response_text);
                    blocked = getBlockedProperty(queue[0]);
                }
            }
        };
        return publik;
    }());

    $P.serialAjax = function (source, callback) {
        $R.Queue.addItem(callback);
        $P.ajax({
            type:       'get',
            url:        source,
            callback:   function (response_text) {
                $R.Queue.itemCompleted(response_text, callback);
            }
        });
    };

/******************************************************************************/
// WRAPS

    // timeouts

    $P.setTimeout = function () {
        return win.setTimeout.apply(win, arguments);
    };

    $P.clearTimeout = function () {
        return win.clearTimeout.apply(win, arguments);
    };

    $P.setInterval = function () {
        return win.setInterval.apply(win, arguments);
    };

    $P.clearInterval = function () {
        return win.clearInterval.apply(win, arguments);
    };

    // styles

    $P.getComputedStyle = function () {
        return win.getComputedStyle.apply(win, arguments);
    };

    // fragments

    $P.createDocumentFragment = function () {
        return doc.createDocumentFragment.apply(doc, arguments);
    };

    // elements

    $P.createElement = function () {
        return doc.createElement.apply(doc, arguments);
    };

    // oo style

    $P.FormData = win.FormData;

    $P.FileReader = win.FileReader;

    // other style

    $P.localStorage = win.localStorage;

    $P.sessionStorage = win.sessionStorage;

/******************************************************************************/
// LOG

    $P.log = function (obj) {
        var logger,
            type,
            temp,
            completed;

        // wrap win.console to protect from IE
        // bind to satisfy Safari

        if (win.console) {
            logger = win.console.log.bind(win.console);
        } else {
            return;
        }

        // validation

        type = $D.getType(obj);
        if (!type) {
            logger("Object did not stringify");
            return;
        }

        // host objects, event ...

        if (type === 'Event') {
            logger('LOG|host|event>');
            logger(obj);
            return;
        }

        // library objects

        if (win.jQuery && (obj instanceof win.jQuery)) {
            logger('LOG|library|jquery>');
            logger(obj);
            return;
        }

        // language objects

        $D.someIndex(['Arguments', 'Array', 'Object'], function (val) {
            if (type === val) {
                try {
                    temp = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 1);
                } catch (e) {
                    temp = false;
                }
                if (temp) {
                    logger('LOG|language|' + type + '>');
                    logger(temp);
                } else {
                    logger('LOG|language|' + type + '>');
                    logger(obj);
                }
                completed = true;
            }
        });

        if (completed) {
            return;
        }

        $D.someIndex(['Boolean', 'Date', 'Error', 'Function', 'JSON', 'Math',
            'Number', 'Null', 'RegExp', 'String', 'Undefined'],
            function (val) {
                if (type === val) {
                    logger('LOG|language|' + type + '>');
                    logger(obj);
                    completed = true;
                }
            });

        if (completed) {
            return;
        }

        // remaining

        logger('LOG|not_implemented|>');
        logger(obj);
        return;

    };

    win[$R.g] = $D.extendSafe($P, $D);

}(window, window.document));
```

Answer (score 2):

From a once over:

- Unfortunate naming

  - `win[$R.g].molist.dom` <- `$R` and `g` and `molist` are unfortunate
  - `function (ref_el, func, con)`  <- `con` ?
  - `$P.HTMLToElement` <- I would go for `$P.HTMLToBlockElement` since you hardcode `div`
  - `win[$R.g] = $D.extendSafe($P, $D);` <- No idea what this would do
- Regex expressions are hard to parse for many developers, you should document what they do and ideally provide an example match
- I would not simply `throw` a string, [I would throw an error of the right type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8987321/7602)
- Avoid anonymous functions, your dont want your stacktrace filled with anonymous functions
- This is not good because the comment is pointless, I see that you found the windows/document/ object, but why are you doing what you do and why copy paste it ?

  ```
  // window object detected

  if (selector === win) {
      this[0] = selector;
      return this;
  }

  // document object detected

  if (selector === doc) {
      this[0] = selector;
      return this;
  }

  // element object detected

  if ($P.isElement(selector)) {
      this[0] = selector;
      return this;
  }
  ```

  Go for something like

  ```
  //window, document or element object detected
  //enlightened comment as to why I set this[0] and return this 
  if (selector === win || selector === doc || $P.isElement(selector)) {
      this[0] = selector;
      return this;
  }
  ```
- Your effects functions need way more commenting on what they do
- `$P.ajax` does not deal with failure at all, you should address that
- `config_ajax.callback(xhr.responseText);` <- Why not return `xhr` ?
- You are not consistently using lowerCamelCase
- `// WRAPS` <- This part seems completely pointless, why wrap those functions?